# What is Write Combining, And why does turning it off make my system freeze?

Tags: windows-xp, integrated-graphics

I've had issues the last few days with my windows XP SP3 system freezing up- I eventually worked out it started after i messed with display settings, and turned off write combining. Freezes often occured RIGHT after the log in screen, though sometimes i got the system running up to half an hour before it froze. I had this issue in VGA mode, safe mode with networking, and standard boots, while, thankfully, standard safe mode worked.

So, my question is, what is write combining, and why would turning it off cause display freezes?

The system is a thinkpad r61, with a intel x3100 graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_combining.  Basically it's a technique whereby devices that support burst mode writing can reduce the number of physical write operations, thereby improving performance.  In the context of Windows XP, most commonly associated with display hardware.

Oddly, *disabling* write combining is often recommended for display freezing issues, not *enabling* it.  Which makes sense: usually something that increases performance does so at the cost of stability.  Sorry, I've got nothing for you on the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Write combining has a major effect in the speed of accessing the MMIO (Memory Mapped I/O) Bus because PCI Memory and essentially Screen Memory are very slow compared to RAM and CPU, In any O.S if you write to screen memory for example without WC (Write Combining) it will result in a mare 10 FPS or even slower, Write Combining is what actually makes Windows show fast 60 FPS graphics without GPU Driver.
Also consider checking your drivers, upgrading your computer and your O.S will be the best solution for you.

Does your screen completely freeze up ? or is it just very slow ?

Comment: Well, this was an old PC... 12 years ago. I honestly don't remember, and the PC in question died at some point in the intervening decade

Comment: Nope. Just a regular guy whose PC was acting funny

Comment: Pleasure to meat u, I am also a normal guy who is working on kernels and device drivers, pretty much a big difference.

Comment: Write combining can be activated on some regions of memory, especially slow memory such as VGA Screen ROM or Devices ROM. It helps me alot when drawing graphics in my OS when there is no high performance GPU driver, what happens is that I should write pixel by pixel and because it is a slow memory it will result in a 10 FPS Video, When I enable write combining my pixel writes are storred in an internal buffer without waiting for them to be written, then they are written in burst mode (like gun shots) without having a big latency impact which can result in more than 100 FPS